# Suggest me a printer appropriate for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing

I'd like to know what printer would work well for Ubuntu 16.04.

It's only for my private use and I like to run a combination of printer and scanner.

If possible, the printer should also support WLAN without having an USB cable in use.

Why is it so difficult these days; asking a simple question?

What I meant with the USB cable; is that I don't like to friggle with a USB cable during the install process. Nothing else.

Comment: I wonder who upvoted this.

Comment: @Pilot6, huh. I'd love to see these kinds of things when I reach 1k

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion. @Pilot6 not me >:)  "If possible it the printer should also support WLAN without having a USB cable in use" There are printers that use wlan with an USB cable?

Comment: Pick one from here: http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Comment: @OwenHines You will never see this when you reach 1k, 20k, 200k, or even if you become a moderator.

Comment: @Pilot6, I mean the vote counts, not individual people

Comment: "Best"? I've been printing for decades, and my main expense is printer cartridges. Are you going to print 100s, 1000s or what pages per month? How fast do you want to print? scan?

Answer (score 1):

While which is best is a matter of opinion and can change from person to person what various reasons.  It's most definitive that you should get a printer of which you can find Linux Drivers and idealistically have Linux support from the manufacturer.

By the way, you can usually find [Open Source](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) for most printers.  I haven't found one yet that I couldn't setup on a Linux computer using generic drivers developed by the community.

Search the manufacturer's site for Linux drivers for their hardware. If they have Linux drivers, you'll have better mileage at trying to get support from them for Linux.

The google command you can use to search a manufacturer site is:

```
site:SpecificSite.com printer drivers for Linux
```

Replace `SpecificSite.com` with the manufacturer's support site.

This is examples of what you will find:

- [hp.com Site Search for Linux printer Drivers](https://www.google.com/#q=site:hp.com+linux+printer+driver)
- [brother.com Site Search for Linux printer Drivers](https://www.google.com/#q=site:brother.com+linux+printer+driver)
- [epson.com Site Search for Linux printer Drivers](https://www.google.com/#q=site:epson.com+linux+printer+driver)
- [lexmark.com Site Search for Linux printer Drivers](https://www.google.com/#q=site:lexmark.com+linux+printer+driver)

Note: *The open source link for drivers is taken from the comments (@Rinzwind).*

Answer (score -1):

I have a HP LaserJet M1212NF MFP. This is a printer and a scanner with document feeder. The laser printer is just black, so no colors. It works using HPLIP. It is a network printer so it is connected to my wireless router and thus reachable through WLAN. Works just fine in Ubuntu 16.04 and other distro's as well. If it's the best? Don't know, but it works. Scanner, document feeder and printer.

Comment: Why vote me down? I took the effort to provide an answer. I can't say anything else, because the LaserJet M1212NF MFP is the only one that I know of working and works very well. Also, one can use it without the USB cable. Oh, I remember that before this one I had an LaserJet 6P, but that one has no scanner integrated and is a real oldtimer these days...